# Error in Kingston DataTraveler 100 USB while installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my notebook with an Intel i5 processor. I have Ubuntu 11.10, and my CD reader doesn't work, so I want to do it from my [Kingston DataTraveler 100](https://www.kingston.com/en/usb-flash-drives/datatraveler-100-g3-usb-3-0-usb-flash-drive).

When I try to run the USB the system tells me that there is an error in the USB, tells me to press any key to continue, and then enters the OS.

The DataTraveler is new, and it works fine, I've already saved some files, and the .iso in it to install Ubuntu from it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to check this out. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: Hi- Thanks for your answer first of all.

I dont't have the startup disk creator. I have ubuntu 11.10, and as it's an old version I can't install anything. What can I do?

Comment: Uhm, you might try just downloading the iso and running it. Anyway, here is a guide I found that might help ya. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux

Comment: Hi. I downloaded the iso and copied it in the usb drive. When I try to run it from the USB I get an error. I reboot the computer, go to options (F12), I select to boot from USB and it gives an error.

Comment: Sounds like the USB is not bootable then. You will need to make the device bootable, which I'm not sure how to do that on older versions of ubuntu. But, you might try this http://bootableusb.net/bootable-flash-drive/

Comment: Also, on a side note have you tried to update to 12 thru the Update manager?

Comment: Hi. The update manager doesn't work, and I can't do anything with this version of ubuntu because it gives me errors. I finally could get the USB to be bootable. I used other computer with windows and used the universal usb installer ([link](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)) to make the the usb bootable. Now I have another problem with this. I'm trying to install ubuntu in my notebook Dell Inspiron Corei5. When I boot from the usb, I got a message from Dell, it says it's something of Dell recovery for Dell computers, which is used to save all the software...

Comment: ...all the software important, I think that it is because of the drivers or something. The thing is that when this windows with this message of dell recovery apperas, the touchpad doesn't work, and I can only press enter, and give to quit, and then to cancel, and I can't go out of there, I just have to shut down the computer. I don't know whats wrong now, but it seems as if it would get to the installation, but I just can't go on.

Comment: The update manager probably does not work since the 11 repos are no longer supported.